# How to make Accordion(CSS+javascript) work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code so far:

```js
var acc;
    acc = document.getElementByClassName('button');

    acc.onclick = function()
    {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

```css
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}

.button{
    display:block;
    height:431px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-style:none;

}

.button:hover, .button.active{
    background: url('pcluj.jpg') ;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<center><button class="button" id="button">CLUJ</button></center>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Right now it doesn't work and I don't know why!! The div doesn't show up when I press the first button. What is the solution? Please help!

It looked like my post was only code so I had to write this in order to be able to post ...........

Comment: any js error on console?

Comment: Why reinvent wheels? Can I advice to use Bootstrap's accordions for example?

Comment: Each button has a different background image when hovered/clicked so I can't assign the same class to all of them.

Comment: @VladJ — The class attribute takes a space separated list of class names, so you can.

Comment: @Ansar I use Sublime Text to write code so I don't have a console

Comment: Your browser will have a console in the developer tools. Open it and you will see it tell you that `document.getElementByClassName is not a function` and that it `Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

Comment: If you are accessing an element by class name then you have to use `document.getElementsByClassName("button")` you have to use `s` in the function like `getElements....`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp check this

Comment: @VladJ will jquery work ??

Comment: @IqbalPasha Of course

Answer (score 1):

javascript：

```
  window.onload = function(){
    var acc;
    acc = document.getElementById('button');

    acc.onclick = function()
    {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

html:
`<button class="button" id="button">CLUJ</button>
 <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
 </div>`

Comment: do you have error message? I use Chrome and it's ok.

Comment: which browser do you use? you can check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) to get more information.

Comment: `nextElementSibling` is probably null

Comment: oh sorry , i remove the tag `<center>`, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it if you are only supporting Chrome and Safari or Mobile Devices is to use the HTML5 **details** element and style it with CSS. You won't even need JavaScript.

Read on: http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2014/09/html5-details-element.html

Basic Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8mthoj5g/1/

```
<details open>
    <summary>Click me to toggle more information</summary>
    <div>The details element is used as a widget to show/hide additional information.</div>    
</details>
```

**Another way** is to use the onclick as attribute on the button - it will work -

```
<button class="button" id="button1" onclick="someFunc()">CLUJ</button>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp05m27p/

Answer (score 1):

Jquery

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  var divPnl = $('.panel');
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  divPnl.toggleClass("show");
});
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/iqbalp95/ef42fm9k/)

Answer (score 0):

**Ideally you would use an established method or existing library for an accordion such as an Unordered List** but what you've got already can be made to work with a few minor changes:

Firstly, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the `.button` element. This returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Iterate through the NodeList using a basic `for-loop` and add an event listener to each item which calls a method to toggle the `.button`'s `active` class.

Rather than find the children of the active .button we simply use CSS2's [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to select the `.button`s next sibling `.panel`

**E.G:**

```js
// Get the .buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button'); 
// For each button
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) { 
  //add an event listener
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
}
// On button click...
function onButtonClick(){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
/*
div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}
*/
.button{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-style:none;
    outline:none;
}

.button:hover, .button.active{
    background:#eee url('http://lorempixel.com/100/20/') ;
    background-size: cover;
}
#button1:hover, #button1.active{
    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/100/20/');
}
#button2:hover, #button2.active{
    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/200/20/');
}
/* adjacent sibling selector to select a .panel next to an button.active: */
.button.active + .panel {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="button1">ONE</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum one...</p>
</div>

<button class="button" id="button2">TWO</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum two...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I make each button have a different background image?

Comment: Sure you can. Just style *each* button separately. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your Javascript code. You are trying to assign a click event handler to an element before it actually exists in the DOM. You are also referring to the div that you are trying to show incorrectly. See below a working JavaScript code with comments and your mistakes fixed.

```
// You need to make sure that the button element exists before trying to attach a click handler to it.
// You can do that by running the function when the onload event is triggered.
window.onload = function () {
    var acc;
    acc = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0]; 
    // You have errors in the above line, "s" is missing in getElement/s/ByClassName, also that method returns an array, not an element, so you need to add [0] at the end.
    acc.onclick = function()
    {
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        // this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        // This does not work because <button> is in <center> and the panel div is therefore not its sibling.

        // there are many ways to reference the panel div, eg:
        var panel= document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0];
        panel.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```